# Why isn't my query finding the results, is this an exact match or contains?

Tags: lucene

My index has the following data:

```
doc.add(new StringField("domain", "examplehouse.com", Field.Store.YES)
doc.add(new StringField("domain", "exampletree.com", Field.Store.YES)
doc.add(new StringField("domain", "exampleapple.com", Field.Store.YES)
```

Now I am trying to return all domains with the term "example" in it:

```
bq = new BooleanQuery().Builder.add(new TermQuery(new Term("domain", "example")))

indexSearcher.search(bq, 100)
```

The query when I print it out looks like:

```
+domain:example
```

Is this the correct type of query or is this an exact match?

Answer (score 1):

TermQueries are always exact matches. In your case a wildcard based query like a PrefixQuery would make more sense: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html

There are multiple wildcard types and you should take care of understanding this:

- prefix (multi ending wildcard) : examp*
- single ending wildcard : exampl?
- mutli leading wildcard : *ample
- single leading wildcard : ?xample

Old but still valid link to lucene docs expaining the query syntax:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html